# Heroku error when pushing code: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: heroku, node-modules, adonis.js

I'm trying to host my adonis JS project on heroku.

I followed https://medium.com/@mazinosukah/how-to-deploy-adonisjs-apps-to-heroku-66741e7cd26f and https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-adonisjs-apps-to-heroku but I ran into an error not described in those sites. (The webapp runs fine locally)

After running `git push heroku herokuMaster:master`

I get:

```
    Counting objects: 1, done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 198 bytes | 99.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Node.js app detected
    remote:
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NODE_ENV=production
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
    remote:
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.13.0
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
    remote:
    remote:        Resolving node version 10.13.0...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.13.0...
    remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building dependencies
    remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
    remote:        added 510 packages from 288 contributors and audited 4026 packages in 15.432s
    remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
    remote:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Caching build
    remote:        - node_modules
    remote:
    remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
    remote:        audited 4026 packages in 3.961s
    remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
    remote:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Build succeeded!
    remote: -----> Discovering process types
    remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
    remote:
    remote: -----> Compressing...
    remote:        Done: 24.4M
    remote: -----> Launching...
    remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
    remote:        Released v9
    remote:        https://myappname.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy... done.
    remote: Running release command...
    remote:
    remote:
    remote: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    remote:
    remote:
    remote: 1 _.transform
    remote:   /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/src/Command/index.js:527
    remote:
    remote: 2 anonymous
    remote:   /app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13807
    remote:
    remote: 3 arrayEach
    remote:   /app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:516
    remote:
    remote: 4 Function.transform
    remote:   /app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13806
    remote:
    remote: 5 Function.commanderAction
    remote:   /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/src/Command/index.js:526
    remote:
    remote: 6 Command.listener
    remote:   /app/node_modules/commander/index.js:315
    remote:
    remote: 7 Command.parseArgs
    remote:   /app/node_modules/commander/index.js:654
    remote:
    remote: 8 Command.parse
    remote:   /app/node_modules/commander/index.js:474
    remote:
    remote: 9 Kernel.invoke
    remote:   /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/src/Kernel/index.js:329
    remote:
    remote: 10 Ignitor._invokeAce
    remote:   /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ignitor/src/Ignitor/index.js:532
    remote:
    remote: 11 Ignitor.fireAce
    remote:   /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ignitor/src/Ignitor/index.js:847
    remote:
    remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
```

I'm not sure why it is complaining about files in node_modules...
Any ideas? I can share more code if necessary.

Comment: Do you define any blueprint in the factory.js?

Comment: @JuniorGantin yes why ?

Comment: Did you fix it Supreme Devil ?

Comment: I mean the default factory.js exists. I haven't really made any changes to it. Should I have? And no it is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my Procfile contents from

```
release: ENV_SILENT=true node ace migration:run — force
web: ENV_SILENT=true npm start
```

to

```
web: ENV_SILENT=true npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a typo with the force flag. I updated the Procfile to the following and it worked:

```
release: ENV_SILENT=true node ace migration:run --force
web: ENV_SILENT=true npm start
```